# Issue with a Black Jack Game, changing a value of an Ace from 11 to 1 when the user points breaks 21

Tags: java, object, arraylist, conditional-statements

So I'm trying to make a Black Jack game in Java.  However, I've been having an issue with making the user's Hand point value drop from when it goes over 21 and has an Ace. I thought this would be simple 'if handArray has an Ace type and points>21 -> change value of Ace'.

But this is proving to be fairly difficult. Maybe I'm overthinking it, but my vrain is fried and I'm tired of looking at this lol.  Here is my code:
Basically I have a Card object with a value, all the cards are stored in an array, then I have Hand object that stores an array of Cards:

```
    int sumUser = 0;
    userHand.points= 0;
    boolean ace=false;
    for(int i = 0; i < userHand.handArray.size(); i++) {
        //System.out.println(userHand.handArray.get(0).type +userHand.handArray.get(1).type );
        
        
        if(userHand.handArray.get(i).type=="Ace") {
            if (userHand.points>21) {
            userHand.handArray.get(i).value= userHand.handArray.get(i).otherValue;
            System.out.println("saved by the ace");
            }
        }
        
        sumUser = sumUser + userHand.handArray.get(i).value;
        userHand.points = sumUser;
        System.out.println(userHand.points);
        
        if (userHand.points>21) {
            System.out.println("Bust, loser");
            
            btHit.setDisable(true);
            btRetry.setVisible(true);
            userHand.handArray.removeAll(userHand.handArray);
            
        }
```

Comment: Get a pack of playing cards. Arrange a hand so that an ace with a value of 11 exceeds the limit of 21. Make a mental note to change the ace to a value of 1. Write down the steps you took. Translate those steps to code. You don't even have to think about it.

Comment: Don't handle the ACE and final points inside the array.  Track the score and an `hasAce` flag and process the ACE and total after the loop.

Comment: Keep in mind that you might have multiple aces.  I would suggest that you create a function that returns the highest score under 22 if possible, and keep it separate from the game logic.  Maybe count your aces and subtract 10 for each until you fall at or below 21?

Comment: @phatfingers That would work, except in Blackjack, if you have two aces only one of them counts as 1.

Comment: @kendavidson I got a working algorithm. Perhaps it's not as efficient, but it works at least.
2

Comment: @dwlakes I understand you may be targeting a specific variation, but if you look at a few sites posting Blackjack rules, it's common to allow both to count as 1.

Comment: @phatfingers Oh wonderful. I guess I can keep it as is, make my own house rules for the game lol. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
       dealerHand.points= 0;
        boolean ace = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < dealerHand.handArray.size(); i++) {
            
            
            //Checks dealer hand for an ace 
            if(dealerHand.handArray.get(i).type=="Ace") {
                ace = true;
                System.out.println("You have an ace");  
            }
        
            dealerHand.points += dealerHand.handArray.get(i).value;
            
            //if the hand breaks 21 and has an ace, the ace value is reassigned to one and the 
            //hand points value is recalculated
            if (dealerHand.points>21 && ace==true) {
                dealerHand.points = 0;
                for( i = 0; i < dealerHand.handArray.size(); i++) {
                    if(dealerHand.handArray.get(i).type=="Ace") {
                        dealerHand.handArray.get(i).value=dealerHand.handArray.get(i).otherValue;
                        System.out.println("Dealer Ace new value "+dealerHand.handArray.get(i).value);
                        
                        
                    }dealerHand.points += dealerHand.handArray.get(i).value;
                    System.out.println("New dealer hand points value "+dealerHand.points);
                }
```

Comment: As a test case, try { Ace, Ace, 10, 9 }.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ya, you're still re-calculating the Aces before you get to the whole score.  With `{ Ace, 5, 3 }` you would have `9` instead of `19` which would make a huge difference based on the fact that dealers have to stick or hit based on their score to `15` (I think, it's been a long time since I've played in a casino).